# C homework: Print "The sum equals: " followed by the value of variable 'sum'

Tags: c

I'm a starting a beginner course on C at my school. The homework was:

> Print "The sum equals: " followed by the value of variable 'sum'

I was just wondering if I did this right.

```
int sum = 387783;
printf(“the sum equals: %d\n”, sum);
```

Comment: You are just four lines of code away from knowing it yourself. You know how to write `main()`, don't you?

Comment: Just one more tip: **never** use beautified, _smart quotes_ `(“ ”)` in code. Use _plain quotes_ instead: `(" ")`

Comment: strongly suggest: complete the function, then post in codereview.com rather than here

Answer (score 1):

You can check it [online](http://ideone.com/w7MWsz) that it works, just follow the link.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int sum = 387783;
    printf("the sum equals: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ideone is not very good for learning, it suppresses a lot of error messages

Comment: the posted answer will cause the compiler to output two warnings about the unused parameters: `argc` and `argv[]`  Strongly suggest using the `main()` function signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: Where's the `int` supposed to be returned by `main()`?